# Win32 C++ using HWND in separate file/thread to start timer

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, c++98

**Background:**

Application Type: Win32 Application

Language: C++ (with C functions as well)

Problem: Want to use main Window Handle in another file.

***Update 1: Using a TCP server in another thread. This server receives information from a client and then needs to start a timer in the program.***

**Project Layout:**

Main File: main.cpp/main.h which has WinMain, WndProc, etc.

Other Generated Files: Resource.h, main.rc, stdafx.h etc generated by Visual Studio

Self Made Files: functions.cpp/functions.h & calculation.cpp/calculation.h

***Update 1: Server thread is in the main.cpp file and the call to start the timer is made on the server thread. I also updated some of the code to more accurately reflect what I have.***

**Info:**

Can I call SetTimer(hwnd, TIMER_INT, TIMER_INTERVAL, NULL) in the calculation.cpp file in some way and make the TIMER_INT timer trigger in the WndProc for WM_TIMER?

So for example (of course foo is defined in calculation.h, etc. for other functions).

```
//calculation.cpp
void foo(HWND hwnd)
{
    SetTimer(hwnd, TIMER_INT, TIMER_INTERVAL, NULL);
}

//functions.cpp

void ThreadStart()
{
    /* This code initializes a working server that is visible to main.cpp */
    /* The Server socket and Accept socket are extern for main.cpp */
}

//main.cpp
HWND hwnd;
int WinMain(...)
{
    //... Set hwnd here
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, ...)
{
    static PARAMS params; //Thread params
    switch(message)
    {

    case WM_CREATE:
        //This initializes a blocking Server (which works)
        params.hwnd = hWnd;
        params.bContinue = TRUE;
        _beginthread(ThreadServer, 0, &params);
        break;

    case WM_TIMER:
        case TIMER_INT:
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Timer was triggered from foo", L"FOO", NULL);
            //continuous messageboxes will appear based on TIMER_INTERVAL if it works...
            break;
        break;

     }
}

void ThreadServer(PVOID pvoid)
{
    ThreadStart(); //calls accept() until client connects
    while(1)
    {
        memset(&RecvBuffer[0], 0, 512 * sizeof(RecvBuffer[0])); //Clear recv
        TCPServer.iRecv = recv(AcceptSocket, RecvBuffer, iRecvBuffer, 0);

        if(strlen(RecvBuffer) > 1){
            memset(&SendBuffer[0], 0, 512 * sizeof(SendBuffer[0]));
                //Clears SendBuffer
            std::string retString = "";
            retString = process(RecvBuffer); //processes RecvBuffer

                if(condition == true){
                    foo(hwnd);
                }

            if(strlen(retString.c_str()) > 0){
                TCPServer.iSend = send(AcceptSocket, retString.c_str(), strlen(retString.c_str()), 0);
            }else{
                retString = "";
                TCPServer.iSend = send(AcceptSocket, retString.c_str(), strlen(retString.c_str()), 0);
            }

            if(TCPServer.iSend == SOCKET_ERROR){
                break;
            }
        }
        //Determine if socket fails and breaks if failure occurs
        //*
        memset(&SendBuffer[0], 0, 512 * sizeof(SendBuffer[0]));
        TCPServer.iSend = send(AcceptSocket, SendBuffer, iSendBuffer, 0);
            if(TCPServer.iSend == SOCKET_ERROR){
             break;
        }//*/

        Sleep(1);

    }
}
```

The issue is trying to pass a reference to hwnd to calculation.cpp from the server thread. I can pass hwnd to the function foo(HWND), but the timer does not set. Is there a way to set a timer in a separate thread or is this not possible? Is there any other workaround to this with using winsock and a server?

Comment: Your code should work as is, and it is safe. What's the problem? There are no pointers in that code. For improvement you can change it to case `WM_TIMER: if(wParam == TIMER_INT){...}` to make sure it's the right timer id. `MessageBox` normally uses `hWnd` for the owner window. `WndProc` should return `DefWindowProc` for default case...

Comment: Sorry, my question before may not have had enough detail. I updated with the more detailed portion of the original issue. I verified that it works with a single thread application, but I am not able to get it to work with the server thread.

Comment: It's still unclear. You are creating a second thread which is separate from the GUI thread. `foo` is called from GUI thread and has nothing to do with that second thread. You should explain what your program is trying to do, and what problem you are running in to. Offering details about VB6 code seems irrelevant.

Comment: I see I must have forgotten to move foo to the thread. I have updated with the foo function in the thread where it is supposed to be. Basically when retString has a certain condition it will call foo

Comment: Documentation for `SetTimer` says *"This window must be owned by the calling thread."* (and I am not sure why that is) so you should call `SetTimer` in the GUI thread `WM_CREATE`. For your worker thread, you can set a global variable, example `g_started = TRUE`, then proceed based on that variable.

Answer (score 1):

As the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer) state that you can't create a timer for a window from a different thread. For you the different thread is the server thread.

Maybe you can post [`WM_TIMER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-timer) message ([PostMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagea)) to the main thread from the server thread when the timer timeout.

Or you need [Synchronization Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/synchronization-objects) for threads synchronicity.